# Fourier transform of a rapidly decreasing function is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, fourier-analysis

Where $f$ is rapidly decreasing, $f: \Bbb{R}$ to itself.  Let it be rapidly decreasing in the sense that $\sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}} |x|^k |f^{(\ell)}(x)| \lt \infty$ for all $k,\ell \geq 0$ and $\ell$th derivatives of $f$.

Given $f$ as above, $\hat{f}$, the Fourier transform of $f$ is bounded.

**My attempt**:
We have that $|f^{(\ell)}(x)| \leq \frac{M_k}{|x|^k}, \ \forall x\in \Bbb{R}$, for some $M_k \in \Bbb{R}$, for all $k, \ell \geq 0$.

Then $|\hat{f}(\xi)| = \left |\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i 2 \pi x \xi} dx \right | \ \leq \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx \leq \ M_k\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^{-k} dx \\ \leq \ M_k\left (\int_0^{\infty} x^{-k} dx +\int_{-\infty}^0 (-x)^{-k}dx \right ) = $

involves evaluating $M_k / x^{-k + 1}$ as $x \to 0$, so where did I go wrong?

**My second attempt**:
$$
M_k\left (\int_0^{\infty} x^{-k} dx +\int_{-\infty}^0 (-x)^{-k}dx \right )= \\
M_k\lim_{N \to 0} \left ( \int_N^{\infty} x^{-k}dx + (-1)^k\int_{-\infty}^N x^{-k} dx\right ) = \\
M_k \lim_{N \to 0} \left( [\frac{1}{-k + 1} x^{-k+1} ]_N^{\infty} + (-1)^k [\frac{1}{-k + 1} x^{-k+1}]_{-\infty}^{-N} \right ) = \\
\frac{M_k}{1-k} \lim_{N \to 0} \left ( 0 - N^{-k + 1} + (-1)^k (-N)^{-k + 1} - 0\right ) = \\
\frac{2M_k}{k - 1} \lim_{N \to 0} N^{1-k}
$$

Still the same issue.

Comment: For $k > 0$, the factor $\lvert x\rvert^k$ is very small near $0$, so a bound on $\lvert x\rvert^k \lvert f(x)\rvert$ doesn't give you much near $0$; in fact it loses information near $0$. Near $0$, you must use $k=0$; $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant M_0$, and $\lvert x\rvert^2\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant M_2$ together give you $(1+\lvert x\rvert^2)\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant M_0+M_2$, and that gives you $f\in L^1$, whence the boundedness of $\hat{f}$.

Comment: Hmm, I think I should make that an answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could I just plug in $k = 0$ in my above set-up, looks like it!  Didn't see that lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for $k > 0$ the factor $\lvert x\rvert^k$ vanishes in $0$, a bound on $\lvert x\rvert^k\lvert f(x)\rvert$ doesn't give you enough information about the size of $f$ near $0$ to work with. You need to look at $f$ itself near $0$, and combine the bounds,

$$\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant M_0 \land \lvert x\rvert^2\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant M_2 \Rightarrow (1+\lvert x\rvert^2)\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant M_0+M_2,$$

and thus

$$\lvert\hat{f}(\xi)\rvert = \left\lvert\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,dx\right\rvert \leqslant \int_\mathbb{R} \lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx \leqslant \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{M_0+M_2}{1+x^2}\,dx = \pi(M_0+M_2).$$